# New Runners are locked and the checkbox to unlock them is disabled

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

I'm running the latest version of on-prem GitLab (version 14.1.0-ee). The last few new GitLab runners I've added show up as locked. I open the runners config in the WebUI and I see that the "Lock to current projects" checkbox for locking them is disabled, but also checked-on, like this:
[image: Lock to current projects]

How do I enable (unlock) these runners?

I see if I assign them to a specific project, then they'll unlock. But if I then remove them from those projects, they lock again.

Comment: When you registered the runner(s), did you use a specific project's registration token, or the Gitlab Instance's registration token (assuming you're running your own GitLab instance and not using Gitlab.com)?

Comment: @AdamMarshall - I used an instance-wide token and yes, I'm using an on-prem instance. I eventually reported this as a bug/improvement thing to GitLab and they quickly implemented a resolution, the ticket for that is here: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/337041

Comment: Awesome, glad you resolved it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This ended up being a usability bug and GitLab has made a change to avoid future confusion on this point. The relevant ticket for this is here: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/337041